# Compression BMP to TGA issue

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, image-compression

I'm new in .net development, so, may be my question is simple.
I need to compress BMP to TGA and decompress TGA to BMP using C#.
How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

There is not support for TGA in .NET. You could use a third-party library like Magick.NET (http://magick.codeplex.com)

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("input.tga"))
{
  image.Write("output.bmp");

  image.Read("output.bmp");
  image.Write("output.tga");
}
```